# AJAX request not showing on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want a user to fill in a website url and when clicking on the submit button I want a ajax request to fire and show the response on the same page in `<div id="test"></div>` but when I fill in the input field and click submit nothing shows. But if I check the console I see the ajax page getting requested.

Here is `pagespeed.html`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="website" name="website">
    <button id="button_1" value="val_1" name="but1">button 1</button>
</form>

<script>
$("button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/lighthouse.php",
        data: { 
            email: $('#website').val() // < note use of 'this' here
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $('#test').html(data);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div id="test">

</div>
```

And here is `lighthouse.php`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // INTRODUCTION RIGHT
    $("#test").text("Let's get in touch");
});
</script>
```

So the jQuery function is not showing on the `pagespeed.html` page because the `<div id="test"></div>` keeps empty.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: $("button") should by $("#button_1")  and I would add type="button" to the <button> tag in your form, as it now still submits your form, acting as a submit button

Comment: Hook to the `submit` event of the `form`, not the `click` of the `button`

Comment: In your `lighthouse.php`, have you tried to just `echo "Let's get in touch";` without the Javascript stuff?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change from

$('#test').html(data);

to

$('#test').html(result);

because